# mysqladmin missing mysqld

Tags: mysqladmin

I'm running percona 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04 lts.  mysql is running well.

root@ip-10-252-175-58:/var/lib/mysql/data# ps -ef | grep mysql
root      2805     1  0 09:18 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     3247  2805  0 09:18 pts/1    00:00:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/ebs0/mysql/data/ --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/ebs1/mysql/logs/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/data/mysql.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/data/mysql.sock

but when i try to use mysqladmin status i get an error message:

root:/var/lib/mysql/data# mysqladmin status
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

I have checked all the config files and haven't found anything that references /var/run/mysqld.  Why does mysqladmin keep looking there instead of /var/lib/mysql/data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your socket file location is different than what mysqladmin is looking for.

In this case you have to fire the command by explicitly giving socket file path in mysqladmin command.

For example :
mysqladmin -socket=/var/lib/mysql/data/mysql.sock